# ECLIPSE FLEX RED5PRO VIDEO CONFERENCE

Tags: jakarta-ee, flex3, red5pro

I want to add a videoconference to my dynamic web project , i saw that  i need red5 to streaming but i dont now how use it if we can help me  please.

Comment: We need significantly more information.  Have you read the red5 docs?

Comment: yes i did but i still have problem how to configure red5 with flex and eclipse